# Running ignite server node

Tags: java, ignite

I want to run some ignite server nodes and make a separate cluster group from them (call it `"WORKER"`). Nodes from this cluster group are supposed to `take()` elements from ignite queue, process it in some way and put something into a cache which is on nodes with cluster group `"CACHE"`. Here is how it looks like:

```
public interface Batch{ }

public class Runner{

    //initialize batchesToProcess as ignite distrubted queue
    Queue<Batch> batchesToProcess;

    //I need Ignite here.
    //@IgniteInstanceResource does not work this way
    //Because this is just a bean declared in ingite spring configuration
    private Ignite ignite;

    public void executeLogic(){
        Batch b = batchesToProcess.take();
        String cacheName;
        String key;
        String value;
        //process Batch b, get 3 strings
        //1. cache name
        //2. key
        //3. value
        IgniteCache<String, String> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheName);
        cache.put(key, value);
    }

}
```

I would like to start this node by running `./ignite.sh _configuration_` with the specified configuration.

The question is I don't know how to write this `_configuration_` so this can be run just by supplying this configuration file to `./ignite.sh`. Maybe I should catch `ContextRefreshedEvent` and put th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Service Grid](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/service-grid) can be useful in this scenario. Create a service and provide it in the `IgniteConfiguration` bean. It will be deployed automatically on startup.

Comment: This is actually offtopic here but anyway. Since ignite spreads data in the distributed queue uniformly across all nodes as specified [here](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/queue-and-set#section-collocated-vs-non-collocated-mode) (non-collocated mode) I would like to process the batch and **put the result in cache on a local node** (to reduce seraizalization and networking cost). Is it possible to do with `IgniteCache`?.

Comment: Yes, it is possible if you put keys on the affinity node. The best way is to send an affinity computation for the key you plan to store. More info here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation#collocating-compute-with-data